# For which functions is the ‘c’ from the mean value theorem the midpoint of the interval?

Tags: calculus

For which functions is the following true:
After applying the mean value theorem on any closed interval [a,b], the resulting point c is the midpoint of the interval. 
I’ve already proven this result for polynomials up to degree 2, any other suggestions as to where to go next?

Comment: I have revised the proof and made it much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the only functions$f$ satisfying this property are polynomials of degree at most $1$.

First note that $f^{\prime }(x)=\frac{f(x+1)-f(x-1)}{2}$ so $f^{\prime }$ is
continuous. [ In fact $f$ is a $C^{\infty }$ function]. Now let $c=\frac{a+b%
}{2}$. Writing $f(b)-f(a)$ as $(f(b)-f(c))+(f(c)-f(a))$ and applying the
hypothesis for each of the terms we get $f^{\prime }(\frac{a+b}{2})=\frac{%
f^{\prime }(\frac{3a+b}{2})+f^{\prime }(\frac{a+3b}{2})}{2}$. Given any $x,y$
take $a=\frac{3x-y}{2}$ and $b=\frac{3y-x}{2}$ to see that $f^{\prime }(%
\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f^{\prime }(x)+f^{\prime }(y)}{2}$ for all $x,y$. (1)
The only continuous functions satisfying this equation are given by $%
f^{\prime }(x)=c+dx$ where $c$ and $d$ are constants. But this gives $%
f(x)=e+cx+dx^{2}/2$. It is easy to see that this function satisfied the
hypothesis only when $d=0$. This completes the proof.

Proof of the fact that $g$ continuous and $g(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{g(x)+g(y)}{%
2}$ for all $x,y$ implies that $g(x)=c+dx$ where $c$ and $d$ are constants:
let $\phi (x)=g(x)-g(0)$. Then $\phi (\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{\phi (x)+\phi (y)%
}{2}$. (2) Put $\ x=0$ in (2) to get $\phi (\frac{y}{2})=\frac{g(y)}{2}$.
(3) Next replace $x$ by $2x$ and $y$ by $2y$ in (2) and use (3) to see that $%
\phi $ is an additive continuous function on $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$. Hence $\phi (x)=dx$ for some constant $d$ and this gives $g(x)=c+dx$ for
some constant $c.$

Comment: The function satisfying this are polynomials of degree at most $2$, not $1$, as the OP mentioned.  Your derivation that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ is correct, but it is incorrect to say "this function satisfied the hypothesis only when $d=0$".  There is no such restriction on $d$: no matter what $d$ is, the polynomial $f(x) = e + cx + dx^2/2$ satisfies $(f(b) - f(a))/(b-a) = f'((a+b)/2)$.

Comment: This property of quadratic polynomials was known (geometrically) to Archimedes. Propostion 24 in his "Quadrature of the Parabola" says the parabolic sector cut off by a chord to a parabola has area 4/3 times the area of the triangle whose vertices are the two chord endpoints and the point on the parabola with tangent line that's parallel to the chord. To show that, Archimedes first showed, for an upright parabola, that the 3rd vertex is halfway between the endpoints of the chords when measured horizontally. That the tangent at this point is parallel to the chord is the OP's midpoint property.

Comment: A related paper by Carter and Lowry-Duda from 2017: https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.124.6.535